# MYSQL INSERT takes too long and each next portion takes more than previous

Tags: mysql, bulk-insert, wordpress

First 1000 takes 8 sec, next 1000 takes 12 sec and each next more and more. I have two databases with 1,5 million rows each. My goal is to fill empty table jf first db with relationship links.

1. Items, categories and relationships
2. Items *(with category column)* and categories

Here is my code:

```
INSERT DELAYED IGNORE INTO `elsnab_term_relationships`
(`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) 
SELECT 
`elsnab`.`elsnab_posts`.`ID`,
`parsed`.`items`.`cat`,
1 
FROM `elsnab`.`elsnab_posts` LEFT JOIN `parsed`.`items` 
ON `parsed`.`items`.`name` = `elsnab`.`elsnab_posts`.`post_title`;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `short` text NOT NULL,
  `full` text NOT NULL,
  `casetype` text NOT NULL,
  `pdf` text NOT NULL,
  `img` text NOT NULL,
  `vendor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `items`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`(255),`vendor`,`cat`);


ALTER TABLE `items`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `elsnab_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `elsnab_terms` (
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `term_group` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `elsnab_term_relationships` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `elsnab_term_taxonomy` (
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taxonomy` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


ALTER TABLE `elsnab_posts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  ADD KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  ADD KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  ADD KEY `post_author` (`post_author`);

ALTER TABLE `elsnab_terms`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`term_id`),
  ADD KEY `slug` (`slug`(191)),
  ADD KEY `name` (`name`(191));

ALTER TABLE `elsnab_term_relationships`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
  ADD KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`);

ALTER TABLE `elsnab_term_taxonomy`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`term_taxonomy_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `term_id_taxonomy` (`term_id`,`taxonomy`),
  ADD KEY `taxonomy` (`taxonomy`);


ALTER TABLE `elsnab_posts`
  MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `elsnab_terms`
  MODIFY `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `elsnab_term_taxonomy`
  MODIFY `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: I do not think insert delayed works for innodb

Comment: You state that the insertions are being executed in batches of 1000 rows each but you present no code for that. Are you getting your metrics on the fly and trying to run the process on  single transaction?

Comment: I tried to procces it with LIMIT statement and saw that each next iteration takes 20-30% more time than previous on even first iterations when DB is almost empty.

Comment: "insert delayed" was the last scream of dying

Comment: To stem future problems:  Avoid prefix indexes, especially in `UNIQUE`.  Don't use `BIGINT` unless you really need more than billions.  Don't use `TEXT` for things that will never be very long.

Answer (score -1):

Solved, using temp table.
With all needed fields without any cross db relations